# How to parse an XML file and retrieve child elements using ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I have racked my brains and also searched in Stack Overflow, but it seems like mine is a different problem. Or maybe it is that I am a newbie to Python. Either way, I would be ever so thankful if you can help me. I have an XML file, excerpt given below, and I need to parse each element, and its children, and save them in a dict. I have tried many things, but I get different errors, and now I am at my wits end!

I have given below the XML file, and a version of my code (after much stripping down after trial and error ways to retrieve child elements):

```
<nmwg:message>
    <nmwg:parameters id="storeId">
        <nmwg:parameter name="ID">NameA</nmwg:parameter>
    </nmwg:parameters>

    <!--Metadata and Data-->
    <nmwg:metadata id="md1">
        <nmwg:subject id="subject-port-A">
            <nmwgtopo3:port id="urn:ogf:network:domaina.net:port:A">
                <nmwgtopo3:name type="logical">portA</nmwgtopo3:name>
                <nmwgtopo3:country>COUNTRY</nmwgtopo3:country>              <!--Optional, can be left empty-->
                <nmwgtopo3:city>CITY</nmwgtopo3:city>                       <!--Optional, can be left empty-->
                <nmwgtopo3:institution>INSTITUTION</nmwgtopo3:institution>  <!--Optional, can be left empty-->
                <nmwgtopo3:latitude>LATITUDE</nmwgtopo3:latitude>           <!--Optional, can be left empty-->
                <nmwgtopo3:longitude>LONGTITUDE</nmwgtopo3:longitude>       <!--Optional, can be left empty-->
            </nmwgtopo3:port>
        </nmwg:subject>
    </nmwg:metadata>
    <nmwg:data id="d1" metadataIdRef="md1">
            <ifevt:datum timeType="ISO" timeValue="2006-12-04T16:43:38.0+0000">                
                <ifevt:ifInOctets>integer-number</ifevt:ifInOctets>     <!--Integer number in bytes -->
                <ifevt:ifOutOctets>integer-number</ifevt:ifOutOctets>   <!--Integer number in bytes -->                
            </ifevt:datum>
    </nmwg:data>
</nmwg:message>
```

And here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pprint
import ConfigParser, os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

dataXMLFile = 'xmlFile.xml'
data = ET.parse (dataXMLFile)
root = data.getroot()

for child in root:
    print ('Tag: ' + child.tag)
    print ('Attrib: ' + str(child.attrib))
print()

domainId = data.findall('{http://ggf.org/ns/nmwg/base/2.0/}parameters/*')
for item in domainId:
    print ('Tag: ' + item.tag)
    print ('Attrib: ' + str(item.attrib))
print()

domainId = data.findall('{http://ggf.org/ns/nmwg/base/2.0/}metadata/*')
for item in domainId:
    print ('Tag: ' + item.tag)
    print ('Attrib: ' + str(item.attrib))
print()

domainId = data.findall('{http://ggf.org/ns/nmwg/base/2.0/}metadata/*/*')
for item in domainId:
    print ('Tag: ' + item.tag)
        print ('Attrib: ' + str(item.attrib))
print()

domainId = data.findall('{http://ggf.org/ns/nmwg/base/2.0/}metadata/*/*/*')
for item in domainId:
    print ('Tag: ' + item.tag)
    print ('Attrib: ' + str(item.attrib))
print()
```

I would like to parse the XML file such that, I can get `portA` value in `<nmwgtopo3:name type="logical">`. I have tried, but I only get `type='logical'` bit from it. Similarly, I would like to extract `COUNTRY` from `<nmwgtopo3:country>`, `CITY` from `<nmwgtopo3:city>`, integer-number (which will be a proper integer value) from `<ifevt:ifInOctets>`, and so on.

I prefer sticking to ElementTree and not use a 3rd party lib, and would appreciate your help in my question above.

Thanks,
Trupsster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [iterparse / iterwalk](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk) docs in lxml documentation.

Using iterparse utility function, you can iterate over the elements of your XML, just like this:

```
from lxml import etree
from cStringIO import StringIO

with open('your_file.xml', 'r') as f:
    context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(f.read()))

    for action, element in context:
        print('{0}:{1} {2}'.format(element.tag, element.attrib, element.text))
```

If you run that code wherever your XML file is, you will see an output similar than this:

```
parameter:{'name': 'ID'} NameA
parameters:{'id': 'storeId'}

name:{'type': 'logical'} portA
country:{} COUNTRY
city:{} CITY
institution:{} INSTITUTION
latitude:{} LATITUDE
longitude:{} LONGTITUDE
port:{'id': 'urn:ogf:network:domaina.net:port:A'}

subject:{'id': 'subject-port-A'}

metadata:{'id': 'md1'}

ifInOctets:{} integer-number
ifOutOctets:{} integer-number
datum:{'timeValue': '2006-12-04T16:43:38.0+0000', 'timeType':
```

So you can see how iterparse/iterwalk functions works.

Comment: Thank you Jose, but is there any way I can do this using the standard lib ElementTree?

Comment: The ``iterparse`` function is from the lxml library. It is an extension over ``ElementTree``, so you are not moving to any 3rd party library at all.

Comment: Right, but when I try the code above, I get an error thus:
ImportError: No module named lxml

:(

Comment: Oh! I yum-installed python-lxml.x86_64, after a bit of googling based on your answer that lxml is an extension on ElementTree. Then I executed your code above and it seems to be working! I shall fiddle around with it and let you know if I have any problems! But first, thank you so much for taking the time out to help me with this! I'm going +1 on all your responses! :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for leaving the chat. Yes, I now see that you were using the Python standard library for XML :P Anyway, I whink you'll do better if you use lxml library, which is pretty well known and a must when you are working with XML docs in Python. Maybe you can better use ``pip`` to install it in your environment when you are working in a project which needs to deal with XML ;)